# Does the Microsoft Surface Pro support multiple external monitors over displayport?

Tags: external-display, displayport, microsoft-surface

Has anyone tested a Microsoft Surface Pro with daisy-chained monitors?

How many monitors are supported and at what resolution?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I have a similar query about hooking up [multiple external displays to a Surface Pro](http://superuser.com/q/612918/804), but not daisy chained.

Comment: No, no answer on this one yet. Haven't been able to test it myself, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work - Ivy Bridge processors only support DisplayPort 1.1, so no daisy-chaining.  (Haswell does, though, so likely the next iteration of Surface will support this).

Comment: Turns out you were absolutely right.  Someone has reported on Twitter that the Surface 2 does support DisplayPort daisy chained monitors:

https://twitter.com/kdawg02/status/397934176881479680

Comment: @masenkablast - Yeah, there wasn't too much doubt about that.  Nice to have confirmation, of course!