# Can the Microsoft Surface Pro drive multiple external monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, microsoft-surface, mini-displayport

I am interested in simultaneously connecting two [Dell UltraSharp 2407WFP 24-inch Widescreen Flat Panels](http://reviews.cnet.com/lcd-monitors/dell-ultrasharp-2407wfp/4505-3174_7-31899303.html) to my Microsoft Surface Pro. Currently I am attempting to utilize a [StarTech Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort / DVI / HDMI Multifunction Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005RD3X3Q) by connecting one monitor to the adapter via HDMI and the other via DisplayPort. Unfortunately, I am only getting video on the Surface itself and the monitor connected via DisplayPort.

Is this StarTech adapter capable of simultaneously driving two monitors? Is the Surface itself even capable of driving two monitors?

Comment: To be clear I realize there is a similar question: [Does the Microsoft Surface Pro support multiple external monitors over displayport?](http://superuser.com/q/549375/804) In my opinion the two questions are different in that the linked question focuses on daisy chaining DisplayPort monitors while this question is about multiple external displays that are not daisy chained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked a Startech rep:

> Just wondering if I can get a bit of product clarification. I'm looking at the MDP2DPDVHD "Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort / DVI / HDMI Multifunction Adapter". I'm wondering if it supports multiple monitors simultaneously, or if it's just a converter for one monitor per adapter?

His reply:

> This is only going to support 1 output display.

So, to accomplish what you want, you may want to look into Matrox's DualHead2Go line.  Specifically the [DualHead2Go DP Edition](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/displayport/):

> The Matrox DualHead2Go DP Edition external multi-display adapter adds up to two monitors to your laptop or desktop computer. It connects to the video output of your system and uses the system's existing GPU to provide high-quality, uncompressed graphics and video across all monitors. Ideal for business and professional users looking to increase their productivity with a dual display setup, this little black box lets you run different applications on each monitor or view one application across two monitors.

Answer (score 6):

I have the Surface Pro and I've it connected to dual monitor with the [Zotac DisplayPort](http://www.zotacusa.com/es/zotac-displayport-to-dual-hdmi-adaptor.html).
It works perfectly with a resolution of 3840x1080 and apart the surface screen.

Comment: How do you connect the Surface Pro to the Zotac? Do you use a mini-display port to display port adapter?

Comment: Is there a Zotac Displayport to dual-link DVI adapter?

Answer (score 1):

All the existing answers have focused on an external graphics adapter or a cheeky Displayport splitter that turns two monitors into one large virtual monitor. However, if you have a **Surface Pro 2**, none of this will be necessary because daisy-chaining of multiple monitors should be supported directly over the DisplayPort output.

To do this, you will need at least one monitor that is DisplayPort 1.2 compliant and has a DP-out port to connect the second monitor to. For more information, see

> http://www.surfaceforums.net/forum/microsoft-surface-pro-2/6500-finally-daisy-chaining-monitors-displayport-1-2-a.html